# How to generate a matrix in a box with lines separating the lines and columns?

Tags: matrices, line, vertical, horizontal

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! For this you do not even need to load a package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|cccc|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\cline{5-8}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\cline{5-8}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\cline{5-8}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course I made no efforts to reproduce the numbers of your screen shot.

Comment: wowwwwwwww very fast marmot :) I was thinking in use \array

Comment: Perhaps adding some `\extrarowheight` would be make it look nicer?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! Yes, of course, there are tons of options to make it nicer. (I think for new users it is better to learn in small steps, so I do not want to overwhelm them with such things because it may then not be clear what it absolutely necessary and what is tuning.)